# How to generate access_token form Flutter and send it to node server?

Tags: node.js, flutter, oauth

I have an OAuth server written on Node.JS, these accept access_token as request, and then it generates JWT, and this JWT is used to unlock the resource from the server. Here is my Node.JS code with Instructions in the Readme file. Link: https://github.com/Rakshak1344/oAuth

1. Need to generate access_token from the flutter.
2. Send the access_token to the node route.

Comment: Have you checked the below answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

You can login a user into your app, which calls your login API written on NodeJS Server. In that API, you can generate token and returned that token in the response of that login service.

In Flutter, you can save that returned token in Shared Preferences and then used that saved token in each and every service till that token expires or user logged out.

Sample Code:

```
Future<String> Login(email, password) async {

    final url = "API_URL";
    var result = null;
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var request = { "email": email, "password": password };
    var body = json.encode(request);
    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

    await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers).then((response) {
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
        prefs.setString('token', json['token']);
        result = response.body;
      }
      else{
        var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print(json['error']['message']);
        result = json['error']['message'];
      }
    });
    return result;
}
```

**Approach 2:**

You can generate token in Flutter by using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/jaguar_jwt) package. This [blog](https://itnext.io/authentication-with-jwt-in-dart-6fbc70130806) can help you in understanding and do your job.

Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to generate access_token from the frontend OAuth and then send it to my backend. How do I generate access_token form the flutter

Comment: JWT has been handled by my backend so no need to worry. I just need to pass the access token to the route, and that route generates a JWT for the user.

Comment: This is specifically on JWT and not OAuth access token, here is the link, please have a look https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Click on Authorize API and select Google OAuth2 API v2 and then you should see your OAuth redirect screen and then you should find the auth code and exchange the code with access_token & refresh token, here I need to generate that access_token

Comment: and that token is JWT Token?